# In SAS, I need a dummy variable for each value with that value in suffix of new variable

Tags: sas

The goal is to have an indicator variable for that specific value, if that makes sense.

Here is my following sample dataset:

```
data test;
    input Patient $ ID V1 V2 V3;
    datalines;
    A   133521  88  254 170
    B   673451  254 99  190
    ;
run;
```

Basically what I need is, for each Patient and ID, I need a dummy variable for each value of V1-V3. For example, in the new data set there would be a variable called V_254, and each Patient and ID would have a 1. There would also be a variable called V_170 that would have 1 for Patient A, and 0 for Patient B. I would think it is something similar to a design matrix.

PROC TRANSREG does something similar to what I want, but it doesn't include all the values due to colinearity (I think?).

```
proc transreg data=test design;
   model class(V1 - V3 / zero=last);
   id Patient ID;
   output out=TRANSREG(drop=_: Int:);
  run;
```

Below also works well, except the same problem arises when both patients have the same value (i.e., 254).

```
proc transpose data = test out = long (rename=(Col1=V_));
    by patient id;
    var v1 v2 v3;
run;

proc transreg data=long design;
   model class(V_/ zero=last);
   id Patient ID;
   output out=long1(drop=_: Int:);
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in two steps.  First, output a dataset that has just patient, id, variable, and value.  Value would be 1 always; variable would be 'v_254'.

```
data vert;
  set have;
  array v_[3]; *this is v_1 v_2 v_3;
  do _t = 1 to dim(v_);
    variable = cats('V_',v_[_t]); *this will be like V_254;
    value=1;
    output;
  end;
  keep patient id variable value;
run;

proc transpose data=vert out=want;
  by patient id;
  id variable;
  var value;
run;
```

You would have 1/missing now, and if you want to get 0s you just post-process that either with a data step or PROC EXPAND (look up 'interpolating missing values' and use zero as the value for the SETMISS transformation (`transformout=setmiss 0`):

```
data test;  *dummy data for example;
  array v_[10];
  do id = 1 to 10;
    v_[id]=5;
    output;
  end;
  call missing(of v_:);
run;

proc expand data=test out=testout;
  id id;
  convert v_:/transformout=(setmiss 0);
run;
```

That requires ETS to be licensed, otherwise use data step.